# Create an array category tree with PHP from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im making a aplication with codeigniter and i was wondering how to make categoire tree structure with php and MySql if all data is in one table... I'm making a menu.

So this is my mysql table example:

```
[id_categorie] [categorie_name] [id_parrent]
       1            Mens             0
       2           Women             0      
       3           Jeckets           1
       4           Thights           2
       5           Pants             1
```

Wanted output is array of arrays similar to this one:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Mens
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Jackets
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Women
            [parent] => 0
        )

)
```

So i could display menu with sub items, like this

```
-Mens  
   -Jeckets  
   -Pants 
-Women
   -Thights
```

Comment: Could you give more details on the result you are looking for ? It's just not enough for us to help (Ordering id_parents ? Wanting a particular PhP structure ?)

Comment: I have updated a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways you could do this.  For example, you could build an array with children tucked under parents.

```
/**
 *  All menu items.  This would come from MySQL, for example.
 */
$cats = array(1 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Mens', 'parent' => 0),
              2 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Women', 'parent' => 0),
              3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Jackets', 'parent' => 1));
$menu = array();
/**
 *  Build array that places children under parents
 */
foreach ( $cats as $k => $v ) {
    if ( isset($v['parent']) && $v['parent'] > 0 ) {
        $menu[$v['parent']]['children'][$k] = $v;   
    } else {
        $menu[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Then loop thru $menu and build your HTML.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Mens
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Jackets
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Women
            [parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Your function works fine for categories with a depth of 1. But be aware:

`$cats = array(same_key => array('id' => same_key, 'name' => 'Mens', 'parent' => 0)`

Answer (score 0):

you will want to write a recursive function in php, here is an example which you will want to modify to fit your code.

```
function getCategoryTree($parentId = 0){

    if($result = $this->database->getCategoryByParentID($parentID)){
        if($result->num_rows){
            while ($resultRow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                 $resultRow['children'] = $this->getCategoryTree($resultRow['parentID']);
                 $data[] = $resultRow;
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```